# Rails and REST confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am confused about how to set up a RESTful rails app. I have some models- Courses, Students, Assignments, and StudentHandsInAssignment. There's a many to many relationship between Courses and Students, a one to many between Courses and Assignments, and two one to many's from Students and Assignments to StudentHandsInAssignment.

Now I am thinking about controllers and routing. From what I have read I want to be RESTful which means making resources. However, I can't quite figure out how to get all of the things I want in the resources supplied by rails.

In particular, I want to have an elaborate view of all the grades for the students in a course. Now, do I use the simple "GET /courses/:id" route and corresponding method in the controller or use something more specific like "GET /courses/:id/view_complete_grade_summary". I think I would like to do something like the latter because I might have multiple different ways of viewing a course. How does one handle this situation and set up that route/controller?

Also, I'll need to have a form to enter in grades in the app. This will create StudentHandsInAssignment objects and store them in the database. But, when I use "GET student_hands_in_assignments/new" to display a form (and eventually submit to call "create") how do I pass around the student id and the assignment id? Should it be something like this:

"GET student_hands_in_assignments/new/:student_id/:assignment_id"

or like this:

"GET student_hands_in_assignments/new/?student_id=1&assignment_id=2"

I guess I am confused about how to get the required info about the student and the assignment into a RESTful url. What is the best way to handle these situations?

Comment: StudentHandsInAssignment? How about... Grade?

Comment: Ha ha... yes, that is probably a better name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one "right" way to organize resources, IMO. My first thought for grading would be student-centric: student/:student_id/course/:course_id/grade, but it could just as easily be course-centric, or both.

I wouldn't have a separate page for entering grades, though, rather something hanging off a student page (list of enrolled courses with in-page, Ajax-centric grade entry) *and* off a course page (list of students with same grade entry scheme). Otherwise there are app transitions that just add cognitive overhead without any benefit.

For things like the course grade summary I'd just have /course/:course_id/grade_summary or whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using 'pretty' URLs is not necessary for a RESTful application, though I find that creating pretty URLs helps me organize my resources helps other maintain their sanity while maintaining my code.

I would consider using this URLs with the scenarios you describe:

```
# Renders the form to be submitted
/students/:student_id/assignments/:assignment_id
```

Add something like the following to your routes.rb:

```
resources :students do
  resources :assignments
end
```

which will call:

```
{controller => 'assignments', :action => 'show'}
```

with the parameters:

```
{id => ':assignment_id', student_id => ':student_id'}
```

As a side note, consider changing the name of your model 'StudentHandsInAssignment' to something else. A student handing in an assignment is neither a Model nor a Controller, it's an action upon a resource. It may make more sense to have a AssignmentController with an action "hand_in" that updates the Assignment model (presumably with a status).

Hope this helps.

Comment: StudentHandsInAssignment is a model in my app. It joins a student and an assignment. An assignment has a name, description, due date. The StudentHandsInAssignment records one student's grade for one assignment.  One of my questions is how to deal with routes/controllers for these join models?

Comment: @MarkM A model is almost always a noun, not a verb. Verb phrase? As a model, IMO, the name makes no sense-handing in an assignment is an  action that references resources. Handing in an assignment is actually a state transition of a student's assignment for a given course. A grade is either an assignment property, or a separate model, that can only be applied to an assignment that's in a handed-in/submitted state.